# ListViewAdapter changing few buttons

Tags: android, android-listview

I created Adapter for list view. I want to click on the button and change text on it. But when I click button few buttons are changed not only this.

This is  ListViewAdapter.java

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Post> {
    private List<Post> mPostList;
    private Context mContext;

public ListViewAdapter(List<Post> postList, Context context){
    super(context, R.layout.post, postList);
    mPostList = postList;
    mContext = context;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    final ViewHolderItem viewHolder;
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.mPlusImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewHolder.mPlusImageButton.setText("A");
            }
        });
    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
    }

    return convertView;
}

    static class ViewHolderItem {

        public Button mPlusImageButton;

        public int position;
    }

@Override
public int getCount(){
    return mPostList.size();
}
```

}

Comment: where is getcount method please share complete code

Comment: ok here is complete class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what you can do create a boolean variable inside your Post class and instantiate it as false whenever button is clicked make it true and inside getView method make use of this variable. Your getView method will look like below.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
final ViewHolderItem viewHolder;
if(convertView==null){
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post, parent, false);
    viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
    viewHolder.mPlusImageButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.someid);
    viewHolder.mPlusImageButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.someid);
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

}else{
    viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
}
Post post = mPostList.get(position);
viewHolder.mPlusImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewHolder.mPlusImageButton.setText("A");
                post.isClicked = true;
            }
    });
    if(post.isClicked)
    viewHolder.mPlusImageButton.setText("A");
    else
    viewHolder.mPlusImageButton.setText("B");

   return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I add final Post post = mPostList.get(position); and it works !

Answer (score 1):

There are some steps you may be bypassing.

**First**
Your adapter is working with real-time objects instead of using an actual data model. What I mean is you're creating your list item real-time instead of loading it from data you stored.

This means several things, the first of which is that the changes you make to the object you created will not persist if that particular view is recreated (which is what happens when you scroll the view)

**Second**
The real-time object you created is a *final* variable, which means it's unchangeable. Which means when you try to set the text variable it should not ever change past the initialization. I'm surprised you're seeing any positive results at all from this test.

I assume you made it final so you could pass it into your `OnClick` method. There is a reason you can't pass in non-final variables. If your adapter changed, and kept a view in place that was outside the scope of that variable you would have a nasty and hard to find bug.

**The Fix**
In order to fix this you're going to have to make a few renovations. The first is to create a data source.

So you probably want to change your adapter to an `ArrayAdapter` and use a String or something similar as your variable, then use those Strings to create the views if your objects in your `OnCreateView` method. You can pass a final integer into your `onClick` handler of your button, and use that integer to access the string in your adapter as well as the current button view.

You can do it!

Comment: I didn't write more code with other textviews and buttons in the element in order to not confuse. So element contains few textviews and buttons, and when I click on the button in this element I want to change for example text view in this particular element, but with the code above, not only this element is changed.